# Spring Security using SAML 1.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-saml

By default the [Spring Security SAML](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) extension provides support for the SAML 2.0 specification.  In order to support integration with a third party provider that does not support that version of specification I need to be able to change my requests to SAML 1.1.

**Is there any setting in Spring Security SAML that allows specification of the version to use?**

I read through these but may have missed it:

- [Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/)
- [API Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/api/)

I was under the assumption that it would automatically pick up the information from the remote service metadata XML.  However, I cannot strictly rely on that due to constraints set by the third party provider that I need to integrate with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the only protocol supported by Spring Security SAML is SAML 2.0. Feel free to get in touch in case you'd like to discuss possibilities of adding support for SAML 1.1.

Comment: That's what I expected after not finding it in the documentation.  Thanks!